# Online Load Testing tool for web application

Tags: asp.net, testing, web-applications

My requirement is to hit a web page 10,000 times in a second and to test performance online so is there any online load testing tool that can fulfill my requirement

Any Help is greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

To run it offline, you probably want [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/). For an online load testing tool, I recommend you google for "online load testing" and you'll get plenty of results.